# How to perform input validation on bash arguments injected with \r?

Tags: bash, metacharacters, confd

I have a bash file, that takes one argument. This is used within ConfD CLI, for a command. However, if the user uses \r metacharacter, it throws my program off.

***Example (on ConfD shell):***

```
somecommand hellooooo\rtest
```

***On displaying $@ within my bash file:***

```
testooooo
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this? Or is there a way to disable use of metacharacter for ConfD CLI itself?

Comment: "displaying $@" how? There are lots of wrong ways to do it. (Any approach that involves `echo` is quite deeply broken; `printf ' -
 %q\n' "$@"` is one of the right ways).

Comment: See the RATIONALE and APPLICATION USAGE sections of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html for some background re: how `echo` came to be broken-by-design, and why it's still around despite that.

Comment: ...anyhow, right now, you aren't showing your actual code, which makes this effectively unanswerable.

Comment: Are you talking about the user using a literal `\r` (backslash character followed by the letter "r"), or a carriage return character (ASCII code 13 aka control-M, sometimes represented as `\r` or `^M` or `<CR>` or...)? Also, how does it throw the program off; does it just display wrong, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: The variable doesn't contain `testooooo`, that's purely a display artifact. It has the correct value, and you can treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, since posting the question I have read up and realized that echo was interpreting the \r. I have used regex on $@ to handle this issue.